# Ruby: How to access a constant from the class a module is included into

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to access a constant held within various classes in a module which I am including into them. As a basic example

```
module foo
  def do_something_to_const
    CONSTANT.each { ... do_something ... }
  end
end

class bar
  include foo

  CONSTANT = %w(I want to be able to access this in foo)
end

class baz
  include foo

  CONSTANT = %w(A different constant to access)
end
```

As the logic for the module is shared across multiple classes I'd like to be able to just refer to the constant (the name of which stays the same in each class, but the contents vary). How would I go around doing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can reference the class module being included into as `self.class` and the use `const_get` or just `self.class::CONST`, with the latter being slightly faster:

```
module M
  def foo
    self.class::CONST
  end
end

class A
  CONST = "AAAA"
  include M
end

class B
  CONST = "BBBB"
  include M
end

puts A.new.foo # => AAAA
puts B.new.foo # => BBBB
```

Comment: Thanks @Vasfed that is exactly what we were looking for

Comment: There's no need to use reflection. You can just as well use `self.class::CONST` without reflection.

Comment: @JörgWMittag you're right, and it is about 2-9% faster, updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the class with `self.class`

```
module Foo
  def do_something
    self.class::Constant.each {|x| puts x}
  end
end

class Bar
  include Foo
  Constant = %w(Now is the time for all good men)
end

class Baz
  include Foo
  Constant = %w(to come to the aid of their country)
end

bar = Bar.new
bar.do_something
=>
Now
is
the
time
for
all
good
men
 => ["Now", "is", "the", "time", "for", "all", "good", "men"] 

baz = Baz.new
baz.do_something
=>
to
come
to
the
aid
of
their
country
 => ["to", "come", "to", "the", "aid", "of", "their", "country"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `::` operator to scope `CONSTANT` to the `BAR` class. The syntax would look something like this:

```
module Foo
  def do_something_to_const
    Bar::CONSTANT.each { |item| puts item }
  end
end

class Bar
  include Foo

  CONSTANT = %w(I want to be able to access this in foo)
end

Bar.new.do_something_to_const # outputs each item in Bar::CONSTANT
```

I'd try to avoid this, however. The included module shouldn't need to know the implementation details of the class for which it's being included.

Comment: The issue here is as you mention, the module should not know the implementation for what it is included. I'm using the same module across many classes and as such could not do it this way. 

I'll extend the original code sample to make that clear.